# find a list of x from n lists

Tags: r

I have a list of 20 lists (each list contain genes of 20 populations) to

I have to find genes (for each population) whose are presented in at least 15 lists

I'm using R

Any help please ?

example:

```
BigList$list1$pop1
BigList$list1$pop2
BigList$list1$pop3

BigList$list2$pop1
BigList$list2$pop1
BigList$list2$pop3

BigList$list3$pop1
BigList$list3$pop1
BigList$list3$pop3
```

My list is like :

[[1]]$pop2
[1] "CFC1"           "ZNF536"         "TRIM67"         "AC092431.3"     "RP11-572M11.4"  "HCG23"          "AC006372.4"     "RP11-6O2.4"     "CACNG3"
[10] "AC129492.6"     "POTEC"          "RP11-862L9.3"   "AC018766.5"     "RP11-506O24.1"  "RP11-397O8.7"   "RP11-54O7.11"   "RP11-335O13.7"  "RP11-392O17.1"
[19] "AC140481.2"     "RP11-284H18.1"  "RP11-370B11.3"  "SLC17A8"        "RP11-474D1.2"   "GOLGA8H"        "RP11-815J21.3"  "CTD-2135D7.2"   "RP11-388M20.6"
[28] "CTD-2034I21.2"  "KRT31"          "USH1G"          "CTC-360G5.9"    "TBL1Y"          "RP11-143E21.6"  "SERPINA10"      "RP11-303E16.3"  "RP11-849F2.5"
[37] "VCAN-AS1"       "OPN4"           "MS4A2"          "LIMS3"          "SYNE1-AS1"      "RP11-881M11.4"  "GCSAML-AS1"     "LIMS3L"         "FBXW12"
[46] "RP11-364P22.1"  "ADAMTS19"       "AC005276.1"     "RP11-513D5.5"   "RP11-68L18.1"   "RP11-402G3.3"   "PGA3"           "PGA4"           "RP11-582E3.2"
[55] "LINC00943"      "AC073657.1"     "RP11-773H22.4"  "ANKRD30B"       "RP11-103J8.2"   "CTA-407F11.8"   "ETNPPL"         "RP11-1M18.1"    "RP11-277P12.10"
[64] "AC105339.1"     "DDX4"           "CTD-2342N23.3"  "RP11-684B21.1"  "NDST4"          "CCDC60"         "U91319.1"       "RGR"            "AC108868.6"
[73] "RP11-480G7.1"

[[1]]$pop2
[1] "RP11-469N6.1" "GDF5"         "NELL1"

[[1]]$ppo3
[1] "RP3-398G3.5"    "AC010091.1"     "RP11-3B12.5"    "RP11-78F17.1"   "C20ORF135"      "CTC-325J23.3"   "DBH"            "FOXE3"          "FOXD4L1"
[10] "AC114730.8"     "AC008697.1"     "RP3-323N1.2"    "RP11-142M10.2"  "AC005616.2"     "DCDC2B"         "RP11-415J8.7"   "LINC00326"      "IL1RAPL2"
[19] "RP11-167N4.2"   "RP11-114H23.1"  "RP11-57A19.2"   "C17orf98"       "XX-CR54.3"      "DLX2"           "RP11-337N6.1"   "RP11-416O18.1"  "RP11-25H12.1"
[28] "RP11-269F21.3"  "LINC00491"      "CTB-43E15.3"    "GABRR1"         "H2BFWT"         "TRPC5OS"        "HTR2C"          "RP11-642C5.1"   "RP11-64P14.7"

[[2]]$pop1
[1] "CNGA3"         "ITLN2"         "RP11-400N13.1" "RP11-331F9.4"  "GPR88"         "LINC01037"     "RP11-255M2.2"  "LA16c-329F2.1" "RP11-154H12.2" "DUXA"
[11] "RP11-36B6.1"   "RP11-12A16.3"

[[2]]$pop2
[1] "AC011893.3"     "ISM1-AS1"       "CA10"           "RP11-301L8.2"   "RP11-1250I15.3" "GABRG2"         "NAMA"           "CLEC1B"         "RP11-458D21.5"
[10] "RGPD4"          "SLITRK3"        "RP3-495K2.2"    "C11orf87"       "RCVRN"          "RP5-1112F19.2"  "RP3-333A15.1"   "RP5-836J3.1"    "METTL11B"
[19] "AC112721.1"     "RP11-761N21.1"  "GRID2"          "GML"            "CLEC2A"         "RP11-834C11.8"  "RP11-406H23.2"  "RP4-715N11.2"   "RHD"
[28] "EYA1"           "TAS2R19"        "GABRA1"         "SLC8A3"         "RP3-510H16.3"   "GRM7-AS3"       "RP11-71H9.1"    "PPEF2"          "TULP1"
[37] "RP11-704J17.5"  "RP11-10C8.2"    "RP11-298H24.1"  "RP11-263K4.3"   "METTL21C"       "AC012317.1"     "CCDC42"         "AC139100.3"     "AF015262.2"

[[2]]$pop3
[1] "SYT10"         "SPATA13-AS1"   "AC064834.2"    "CTD-2544H17.2" "AC106786.1"    "RP11-25L3.3"   "IMPG1"         "DDX4"          "RP11-50B3.4"

I have to find intersections to find (List with genes in at least:
2 lists
3 lists

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the output of `BigList$list1$pop1` in the question, please?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).